# What is the convention for names and ids?

Tags: java, node.js, naming-conventions, loopback

Is there a convention for where the id should go?

For example:
UserId
IdUser

Or

User_id
Id_user

Mysql uses iduser . So i think that's the best?
I was working with loopback and someone told it, it should be user_id and i got used to id_user

Answer (score 0):

For variable -Internal words start with capital letters.

For Constants - The names of variables declared class constants and of ANSI constants should be all uppercase with words separated by underscores ("_").

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

consistency is most important.

Comment: Thanks mate! I know. I wanna learn to write the best code possible. But i'm not sure wether i put id_name or name_id.